# Issue with local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

i am trying to get notification when date of array become same as current date this code is i am using for this task

```
NSDateFormatter *Form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Form setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    for (int i=0;i<_convertedBdates.count;i++)
    {
        NSDate *date =[Form dateFromString:[_convertedBdates objectAtIndex:i ]];
        NSLog(@"date%@",date);

    if(notification)
        {
            notification.fireDate = date;
            notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            notification.alertBody = @"New ";
            notification.alertAction = @"View";

            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
```

suggest me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you put this code in your app delegate?

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Notification Received, %@, set for date %@", notification.alertBody, notification.fireDate);
}
```

if problem persist then i am here :)

Answer (score 0):

If your NSDate is less than the current date then notification will not be fire. If you are setting notification date on the user birthdate then this will happen.

If your application is in running mode then :

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

above method is called.

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!